# What is the name of this chaos theoretic transformation?

Tags: chaos-theory

I once read an article about chaos theory, which I can no longer find, that went through the following example:

Suppose you take a rectangular picture of Henri Poincare, and stretch it out vertically by grabbing diagonal corners and pulling in opposing directions (while preserving area). Then, cut out the triangular pieces of the picture which are outside the original rectangular border, and paste them back into the picture in the "gaps" left by the other two corners, making the picture a rectangle again, but slightly chopped up. Repeat this process over and over. Eventually the picture will just look like static, but after ~200 iterations or so, the picture ended up looking like the original Poincare picture, but staticy.

Does anyone know what this transformation is called, and where I can find out about it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map ?

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! Interestingly, repeated iterations of this one seem to lead to a flawless recreation of the original, whereas the one I read about lead to the the original image with some slight static/noise over it. Any idea why that might be?